# Allowing existing users to 'fork' a project in a Project Management tool

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am designing a project management app and I want my users to be able to 'fork' an existing project in the database. For instance, `@user1` will create a project and `@user2` may want to modify that project, so `@user2` will click an option to **'fork'** it.
When that happens, the existing project will be pretty much duplicated for `@user2`, except he/she will be able to modify the contents of it.

I was thinking of that nested attributes might do the trick, but I don't think that is the correct method to go about this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean you want user2 to have a separate, independent copy? (Then "fork" is just a way to get started quickly based on someone else's project.) Or do you want user2 to see this as her own project, but changes by one user will be seen by all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [`ActiveRecord::Core#dup`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Core/dup) method.
From the page:

> Duped objects have no id assigned and are treated as new records. Note that this is a “shallow” copy as it copies the object’s attributes only, not its associations. The extent of a “deep” copy is application specific and is therefore left to the application to implement according to its need. The dup method does not preserve the timestamps (created|updated)_(at|on).

In short, `@project.dup` will **build** a new `Project` object with all parameters same as `@project` except - `id`, `created_at`, `updated_at` fields. `@user2` can do modification on this newly build object and then `save` it. This mimics the `fork` feature.